# unable to rename pre uploaded file on uploading another file of same name

Tags: php, html

I am unable to rename a pre uploaded image, say "file1.jpg", when uploading another file with the same name.

I am saving both files in a folder named "uploads" on the server's root folder. Thus, I need to rename the previous file name to something other and then save the new file as "file1.jpg". I have no idea about how to do this in PHP. Please, provide any hints or code if possible.

Comment: It generally is not a good idea to store uploaded files under the name specified by the client. One of the reasons is indeed the risk of name collisions. It makes much more sense to use phps unique name functions for this: http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php The name the file is saved under internally is not of interest anyway.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file ?

Comment: actually the files are images